# Как отобразить html страницу для ошибки 404

Tags: django

Недавно я начал изучать django и у меня появилась проблема. Дело в том что я хочу чтобы если пользователь ввел несуществующий адрес то сайте на отображалась бы определенная html страница. Я использую `HttpResponseNotFound`, но пока я могу лишь отображать какой ни-будь текст который написан внутри `HttpResponseNotFound`. В общем я хотел бы отображать полноценную html страницу с помощью `HttpResponseNotFound` но не знаю как это сделать.

Стоит уточнить что я не могу использовать `render()`.

Вот views.py:

```js
from logging import exception
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound
from django.http import Http404

def index(request):
    return render(request, "main/index.html")

def about(request):
    return render(request, "main/about.html")

def pageNotFound(request, exception):
    return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Not found...</h1>')
```

А вот что я написал в urls.py:

```js
handler404 = 'main.views.pageNotFound'
```

Хочу чтобы вместо "Not found..." на сайте отображалась моя html страница

(Простите, я просто не знаю как правильнее сформулировать свой вопрос)

Comment: Ну, просто внутри pageNotFound напишите `return render(...` как обычно?

Comment: @andreymal А так можно было??? Спасибо большое, вопрос решен.

Comment: (на всякий случай проверьте, что оно действительно возвращает ошибку 404, а то я точно не помню, может в render нужно будет параметр `status=404` дописать)

Comment: Проверил, вроде все работает